# Original skeleton position (Fbx import)

Tags: animation, binding, 3d, 3dsmax, fbx

I was thinking that you need a deformer to read the clusters etc to be able to get the original (usually T pose) position of the skeleton.

Also FBX supports poses etc but never had a file that implemented it.

But my surprise was that importing an fbx file into 3dsmax without any mesh inside if I uncheck "animation" I get the T pose.

Any idea about it?

Thank you in adavnce

Answer (score 0):

FbxCluster has GetTransformMatrix and GetTransformLinkMatrix. The former returns the original transform of the bone (that should be used to initialize the skinning), and the latter the corresponding orientation of the skinned node. Additionally, the skin node can also have "geometric rotation". I don't think there's anything more than that.

Comment: Infortunatly you cannot get clusters if you have no mesh (skeleton only file)

Comment: i think those clusters are only useful to set non-default skinning transform. if there's no skinning, they would make no sense. if you need poses, maybe you can just use single-frame animations?